# Rotating encryption keys for a large database

Tags: database, encryption

We have decided (for a long list of technical reasons) to do Application Level encryption of our data before we write it to the database.

That works fine, but at some point we would like to rotate the encryption key.  That means re-writing EVERY record in the database.  What if your database has 50 billion records?

I'm not aware of any database technology that can just re-write 50 billion records in a reasonable amount of time without stressing the database.  Maybe some distributed databases can, but they tend to suffer from compaction problems if you flood them with updates.

So how do people generally rotate keys on a large database?   Do they throw a ton of hardware at it?  Or do they just wait for months for it to complete?  Do they NEVER rotate the encryption keys?  Or is there some other fancier solution?

I'm not naming our brand of database because I'm open to using any brand of database that can update 50 billion records in less than a week without using a huge amount of hardware.  It would be such a waste to build a monster database 1000x bigger than we need just to handle the spikes in re-encryption traffic.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed re-encrypting all records would be big hastle.
You could take inspiration from aws https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/rotate-keys.html

You can create 2 layer encryption - encrypt each record with its own random key and encrypt the record key with the master key. When rotating the master key you need to re-encrypting only the record keys which can be demanding as well, but if it must be done, it is must be better than re-encrypting all data.

Comment: Thank you!  I love that solution!  Sometimes I wish we had used AWS because those guys already have all of these problems solved.  :)